# Performance is slow when Replacing/updating a string of a table row[bulk data] in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-update

I want to update `formatted body` column of the below main table called `posts`which has below `schema` with dummy data-

[image]

Now, i want to `replace/update a substring` [i.e. `source` with the `final URL`] from the above formattedbody column.[total `5335` records in excel sheet]

[image]

For the same i've written below query -

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1
DECLARE @SURL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @FURL nvarchar(max)
WHILE ( @LoopCounter <= 5335)
BEGIN
    SET @SURL = (select sourceURL from temptable where ID = @LoopCounter)
    SET @FURL = (select [TargetURL] from temptable where ID = @LoopCounter)
update posts
Set FormattedBody=REPLACE(CAST(FormattedBody as NVarchar(Max)),@SURL,@FURL)
Where SectionID = 95 and postlevel=1 and CAST(FormattedBody as NVarchar(Max)) like '%' + @SURL + '%'              
    SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1
END
```

`temptable` contains the data of the excel sheet `[i.e. ID,sourceURL, and TargetURL]`.

Above query works as expected but the `performance is too low`, as it loops through all the rows from posts table [huge data] for `5335` records.

**Currently, it updates only 3 records/minute.**

Any suggestion/help is appreciated! :)
Thanks!

Comment: We generally prefer sample data as *text* rather than *images* (Ideally a table variable declaration and an `insert` statement). We can't copy & paste images into management studio to start working on a solution, and we don't need the typing practice (not to mention that you're excluding people who use assisstive technology for browsing SO)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just wanted to replace a string with TargetURL in `formattedbody column`, any indexing to do to improve performance?

Comment: I assume `FormattedBody` can contain multiple matches for any given sourceURL and may contain multiple sources also? If so, this looks like this really isn't a good fit for T-SQL, which has generally poor string processing functionality.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, you are right! `FormattedBody` can contain multiple matches for any given `sourceURL` which should be replaced with the respective `TargetURL`

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use `while` and `update`, I would use `UPDATE .. JOIN` instead of  `while` and `update`.

If there isn't any relationship between `temptable` and `posts` tables, you can use `CROSS JOIN` (Descartes product) let every `sourceURL` and `[TargetURL]` `temptable` columns to mapper with `posts` table then update.

```
UPDATE p
SET FormattedBody = REPLACE(CAST(FormattedBody as NVarchar(Max)),sourceURL,[TargetURL])
FROM posts p
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT sourceURL,[TargetURL]
    FROM temptable 
    where id <= 5335
) targetDt
Where p.SectionID = 95 and p.postlevel=1
```

Comment: This won't do what you think, since it effectively attempts to update the same target rows 5000 times (number of rows in temptable). *Which* update takes effect is not defined, but the one thing you can be sure of is that if `FormattedBody` contains two matching sourceURLs, at *best* you'll see the effects of *one* of the replacements. In all likelihood though, you're highly likely to get the result from one of the `REPLACE`s that didn't find any matches at all.

Comment: I.e. all updates are computed as if they're applied *in parallel*. You don't end up processing the *result* from any `SET` action in a "subsequent" `SET`.

Comment: E.g., using this setup - `declare @posts table (formattedBody nvarchar(max), SectionID int, postLevel int)
insert into @posts (formattedBody,SectionID,postLevel) values ('abc def',95,1)
declare @temptable table (id int, sourceUrl nvarchar(max), targetUrl nvarchar(max))
insert into @temptable (id,sourceUrl,targetUrl) values (1,'abc','zyx'),(2,'def','wvu')` and changing your update to reference the temp tables, you'll *either* see `zyx def` or `abc wvu` in the table after the update has been applied.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding

```
and CAST(FormattedBody as NVarchar(Max)) like '%' + @SURL + '%'
```

to the where condition in the first place, because the way you wrote it, I think ALL the records are updated EACH time, whether the FormattedBody contains @SURL or not.

Comment: This should actually help.  I wonder if the OP has tried it.  Note that that the `case` should not be necessary.

Comment: Operator `LIKE` may not help here, because i want to replace the `exact string`

Comment: @PPB, what do you mean, "I want to replace the exact string"? What I'm suggesting here is, avoid updating rows when the FormattedBody does not even contain the string to be replaced. It does not have anything to do with the replacing part.

Comment: @CrimsonKing could you please check my updated query/script..and revert

Comment: @PPB, I see that you added the condition I suggested. But as I don't have any test data, I have no clue whether the suggestion solved your problem or not. Is there any improvement in the performance of the update, or is it still the same?